# Hide collection (child) inside another collection (parent) parent - Python

Tags: python

How would you go about hiding specific collections inside a specific collection?

Right now I have this code that get's two variables( child name and parent name) from a YAML file. What I need it to do is first go to the parent collection and inside this collection hide the child.

````
 for group, value in collections.items():
    child = value['id']
    parent = value['cat']
            
    # Set collection
    bpy.data.collections[child].hide_render=True
```
````

Comment: You don't need to access the parent to hide the children. Unless I'm missing something ?

Comment: @Gorgious Hey you're right. Strange that I didn't notice it before. Thanks!